# Qt: Show Edges for 3D Cuboids

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I am using [Qt3D](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qt3d-index.html) to draw intersecting cuboids.Every thing is fine expect for the edges as they don't appear.I checked for properties in `QCuboidMesh` and `QPhongAlphaMaterial` but I couldn't find such one.

[image]

The code:

```
SceneModifier::SceneModifier(Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity)
    : m_rootEntity(rootEntity)
{

    //Outer Cuboid shape data
    cuboid = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh();
    cuboid->setXExtent(4);
    cuboid->setYExtent(4);
    cuboid->setZExtent(8);
    // CuboidMesh Transform
    Qt3DCore::QTransform *cuboidTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();

    Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial *cuboidMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial();
    cuboidMaterial->setDiffuse(QColor(QRgb(0xff0ff0)));
    cuboidMaterial->setAlpha(0.5);

    //Cuboid
    m_cuboidEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(m_rootEntity);
    m_cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboid);
    m_cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboidMaterial);

    // Inner Cuboid shape data
     cuboid2 = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh();
     cuboid2->setXExtent(2);
     cuboid2->setYExtent(2);
     cuboid2->setZExtent(8);


     Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *cuboidMaterial2 = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
     cuboidMaterial2->setDiffuse(QColor(QRgb(0xffffff)));

     //Cuboid

     m_cuboidEntity2 = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(m_rootEntity);

     m_cuboidEntity2->addComponent(cuboid2);
     m_cuboidEntity2->addComponent(cuboidMaterial2);

     Qt3DCore::QTransform* cuboidTransform3 = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
     cuboidTransform3->setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(0.1f, -0.1f, 0.0f), 45.0f));

     m_rootEntity->addComponent(cuboidTransform3);
}
```

Comment: [This example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-wireframe-example.html) should provide a lot of the details you're looking for.

Comment: The output is exactly what I need but how to achieve is still unclear.The created `Wireframematerial` uses 2 attributes to set the edges which are `lineWidth` and `lineColor` which I can't find in the c++ [QMaterial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qmaterial.html) Class or any other subclass.

Comment: lineWidth and lineColor are properties added to the Material QML type that inherits from QMaterial (see the WireframeMaterial.qml file).

Comment: Yeah I've seen this but it's not clear how these 2 added features are used. I don't know how things work in QML but I don't think that just adding the 2 attributes will solve this issue in c++.

Comment: Oops!  I've just realized the online docs are incomplete.  The properties in question are used as uniforms in the fragment shader but that file is missing.  You'll have to download the [latest qt source](https://www.qt.io/download/) to get it.